# jQuery .before not including divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So there is a h2 that contains the following class `entry-contentH2` and I'm simply trying to include the following divs before that h2 but it's not even showing anything. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't adding it, because when I try it without any divs and I test with just **text** it works.

```
jQuery(function($) {    
    $(".entry-contentH2").before("<div class="video_player"><iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$recipe->recipe_video.'?fs=1" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>");
});
```

What is the reason as to why .before doesn't work in this case?

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/or9Lbbq0/2/

Comment: Please include the HTML upon which this JavaScript runs. There is nothing in your code (except for the aforementioned quote escape issue) which would cause it not to work.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've included a jsfiddle above.

Comment: please include errors from console.

Comment: Also, please make it easier on everyone and just include a [mcve] in the question itself, not at an external site.

Comment: Your fiddle continues to have the same problem with unescaped quotes so you might want to fix that there as well...

Answer (score -1):

Your iframe is most likely being blocked by youtube. External websites such as:

- youtube.com
- google.com
- stackoverflow.com
- etc.

are not loading in your frame, is because they are intentionally leveraging some sort of Frame Killer.

Suggested reading:

- [Framekiller (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller)
- [Busting a tough FRAME killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349628/busting-a-tough-frame-killer)

[see simular problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284217/iframe-and-external-website)

Comment: Thanks but that I already knew it isn't the problem. It's just not moving divs, iframes, but if I include just text without any div it includes it before the h2. But thanks for your response.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change the inner or outer `"` to `'`

like so

```
jQuery(function($) {                       //V here       V
    $(".entry-contentH2").before("<div class='video_player'>hi</div>");
});
```

or so

```
jQuery(function($) {           //V here                    and here V 
    $(".entry-contentH2").before('<div class="video_player">hi</div>');
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1382873/)

Comment: Wasn't me, someone went on a downvote spree on this post.